# scroll one element at a time using mCustomScrollbar

Tags: jquery, mcustomscrollbar

How to make sure that on scrolling elements one element at a time using mCustomScrollbar. I have following html:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

On scrolling `ul` only one `li` should scroll at a time i.e no element should skip scrolling.

Comment: You mean on mouse wheel one `li` scrolled?

Comment: Yes, one li at a time

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollAmount` property in [`mouseWheel`](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#plugin-data-mouseWheel-scrollAmount) object.

```
mouseWheel:{ scrollAmount: integer }
```

> Set the mouse-wheel scrolling amount (in pixels). The default value "auto" adjusts scrolling amount according to scrollable content length.

```js
$("ul").mCustomScrollbar({
  mouseWheel:{ 
    scrollAmount: 100
  }
});
```

```css
ul {height: 200px}
li {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```